# Magento 2.3 - what's in the Default attribute set? (migration wiped it)

Tags: attributes, magento2.3, attribute-set

I have used the Data Migration Tool and now am cleaning my migrated attribute sets, wanting to remove attributes that dont make sense. My attribute sets have many groups called Migrated_ and a few attribute groups which are original, but most of them contain very little. I suspect that if an attribute was in my migration, it is in my migrated groups and not in the original default group it should be.

I obviously don't want to remove attributes that are used by functionality and I would also move the

But somehow as a result of running the tool, the Default attribute set has only 5 attributes in it. That's clearly not right!

I have been looking around the documentation for even a set of screenshots that would show me the contents of the default attribute set but can only find the top bit. It's frustrating.

Sure, I can install another M2 somewhere or try to reverse-figure from old SQL and code but maybe there's a reference somewhere that shows the attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have attached screenshots of Product attributes with default attribute sets.

[image: Product attributes with Default Attribute set]

[image: Content, Pricing and other group]

[image: Other groups]

Comment: that's what I need, only probably one or two more to see whats below the scroll.

I'm missing many of these attributes altogether, that's worrying!

Comment: Do you want to check attributes from Content group also?

Comment: the whole set for this - content, prices, inventory
It's becoming clear that the data migration tool still cannot be trusted :S

Comment: I have updated the answer. Added new screenshots.
Request to approve and upvote the answer. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! I'm probably not the only one affected - now I have to go figure out what the official data migration tool has done and help it get fixed

Comment: @KazimNoorani Any help thanks https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/318269/57334 after migrated Attribute Set "Default" Not Available, what i need to do?